PyTorch: calculating model accuracy for approximation problems
There are some SO posts on calculating accuracy of a classification model in PyTorch, but I how do I calculate accuracy of an approximation model?
For example, for classifications, I can usually count, per-class, the amount of hits, divided by the total validation set size: correct_count / len(validation_set)
However, for an approximation problem, I have a model that predicts y for certain x values. When I run validation, I get y_pred values that are not identical to the original y values of the function. I still want to be able to calculate an "accuracy" for this model. What is the best way to do it?
I was thinking of, for example:
avg(abs(y - y_pred)) / (max(y)-min(y))
But maybe there's some best practice?

There is a metric called Mean Average Percentage Error (MAPE) which, calculate the error percentage of the model wrt the truth value:
MAPE = avg(abs((y-y_pred)/y))

You can refer to here to learn more about MAPE
